# MVC 3 valid XHTML for Ajax.BeginForm fails?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, xhtml-1.0-strict

How is the MVC 3 using Razor view engine supposed to pass W3C xhtml validation?

TOP of page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> .......
```

My FORM....

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("CreateAccount","Home",null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST", OnBegin="CreateOnBegin", OnSuccess="CreateOnSuccess"})){ .......
```

W3C validations errors:
***there is no attribute "data-ajax"***

```
on="/en/Home/CreateAccount" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="CreateOnBegin" d…
```

*** there is no attribute "data-ajax-begin"**
** there is no attribute "data-ajax-method" ***
there is no attribute "data-ajax-success"
there is no attribute "data-val"

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The First Name? field…
```

Comment: Also tried making the directive transitional rather than strict...same errors via W3C....?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be validating against HTML5, not XHTML.  That's the MS strategy for MVC going forward. I'd simply use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: ok thank you...saw that '<!DOCTYPE html>
' in the default sample project but didn't understand the difference between XHtml and HTML5 I guess...thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As tvanfosson stated above, use [HTML 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5), which is much more lenient than XHTML, but has well-defined parsing rules, unlike HTML 4.01 and before.

See also this question: [HTML 5 versus XHTML 1.0 Transitional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256953/html-5-versus-xhtml-1-0-transitional)